# QFT field being operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators

Why is it necessary for fields to be operator valued in quantum field theory instead of just having scalar amplitudes?

Comment: QFT is the theory of operator valued fields. It's not just necessary, they are operators by definition.

Comment: A classical field is an infinity of normal mode oscillators. Why shouldn't its quantization not be an infinity of normal mode quantum oscillators?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question: as mentioned by Prahar quantum fields are operator-valued by definition. Perhaps your question is about why is it a good idea to define quantum fields and study a theory where the interactions are built out of them. The answer is essentially given in the first five chapters of Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields Volume 1 and it basically boils down to it being the simplest way to construct a theory compatible with relativistic symmetry and cluster decomposition.

Comment: What I mean is that classical fields are defined locally. Why do we need to change this to define quantum field? I do understand that they are defined that way, but isn't there any explanation to why it was formulated this way?

Comment: As it stands, teh quetsion is quite broad. Do you understand why, e.g. position and momentum are operators in QM rather than scalar functions as in classical mechnics?